# Is it possible to be notified by PayPal when an order is shipped?

Tags: php, paypal, notifications, e-commerce, paypal-ipn

I have PayPal Express checkout integrated in our website.

The shipping information is passed on to PayPal so that I can us PayPal's print shipping label feature.  Once a label is printed for a specific transaction, that transaction is marked as such in the account overview.

Currently I am copying and pasting the tracking number into my website order so as to notify the customer that the order has shipped.

I figured it might be possible to automate that by checking with PayPal's API to see if an order has been shipped and, if so, get the tracking number.

I have not been able to find anything but this made me wonder on [PayPal's IPN Summary Page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)

> Instant Payment Notification (IPN) notifies merchants almost instantly
> about transaction events, such as:
>
> [...]
>
> Merchants can act based on the information they receive. For example,
> they can:
>
> Update their inventory.
>
> Email a purchase confirmation.
>
> Trigger order fulfillment.
>
> Enable download of digital media.
>
> Update their customer list.
>
> **Email a shipping notification.**
>
> Issue a refund.
>
> Update accounting-related information.

"Email a shipping notification" caught my eye.

Why would they mention that if it were not possible to get tracking info from PayPal IPN?
Yet I have been unable to find anything.  Any insights?

Comment: That is a rather frustrating thing to see.  I've been begging for shipping notifications for years, but they still aren't available.  I work with IPN very heavily, so I'm pretty I would have noticed if they started sending IPNs when shipping labels were printed.  That said, I'm going to reach out to my PayPal Partner and see if there's something I've missed.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I'm guessing you'll get a faster response from them than I would :)  Honestly, I hope you've also missed it, but I kinda doubt it...

Comment: Unfortunately, the info I got is that no, they still not have this feature.  I told them they should remove that bullet point from the page you referenced and they basically thanked me for the feedback but didn't say whether they were going to change that or not.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not the method you are looking to use, an option available is when creating the shipping label in PayPal, you can enter in the customers email address in the form with their address and they will then receive an email from PayPal with the shipping information.

Comment: If I have to copy and paste, I prefer the way I am already doing it.  I copy/paste the tracking number into my web order, then MY website emails the user.  That way I don't have a third party (PayPal) keeping my customers up to date.